# Evaluation of Definite Integral

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x\sin 2x \sin 3x}{x}dx$

$\bf{My\;Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x\sin 2x \sin 3x}{x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\sin 3x\cos x\sin 2x}{x}dx$

So we get $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\sin4x+\sin 2x)\sin 2x}{x}dx$$

So $$I=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos2x-\cos6x+1-\cos 4x}{x}dx$$

Now How can i solve after that , Help me

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't your last line imply the answer is $\frac{1}{4}( \gamma +\text{Ci}(π)-\text{Ci}(2 π)-\text{Ci}(3 π)+\log(6 π))$?

Comment: Is the upper bound equal to $\frac\pi2$ or is it equal to $\infty$?

Comment: To MXYMXY I did not understand it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I don't think the integral converges if the upper limit is $+\infty$. The trigonometric part is "essentially" positive over a period.

Comment: what context did this come up in? Are you sure it has an elementary closed form?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\cos\pars{2x} - \cos\pars{6x} + 1 -\cos\pars{4x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{2x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{6x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{4x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos\pars{x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{3\pi}{\cos\pars{x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos\pars{x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\mathrm{Ci}\pars{\pi} - \ln\pars{\pi} - \gamma} -
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\mathrm{Ci}\pars{3\pi} - \ln\pars{3\pi} - \gamma} -
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\mathrm{Ci}\pars{2\pi} - \ln\pars{2\pi} - \gamma}}
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 4}\bracks{%
\mathrm{Ci}\pars{\pi} - \mathrm{Ci}\pars{3\pi} - \mathrm{Ci}\pars{2\pi}
+ \ln\pars{6\pi} + \gamma}} \approx 0.8998
\end{align}

$\mathrm{Ci}$ is the [Cosine Integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Thanks Felix Marin, But How can I calculate value of $\mathrm{Ci(\pi)}$

Comment: @juantheron I guess you have to use either a numerical calculation or/and some symbolic handling software.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** $$ \int f(x) = F(X) + C \Longrightarrow \int f(ax+b) = \frac{1}{a} \cdot F(ax+b) + C$$

**Hint 2:** $$ \int \left(f(x) + g(x)\right) = \int f(x) + \int g(x) $$

**Hint 3:** $$ \int \frac{\cos x}{x} = Ci(x) + C$$

**First step:**
(use hint 2)
$$
4I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos2x-\cos6x+1-\cos 4x}{x}dx =\\
=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{x} + 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos 2x -1}{2x} - 6 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos 6x -1}{6x}
- 4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos 4x -1}{4x}
$$
Now let $f(x) := \frac{\cos x - 1}{x}$  so
$$
4I = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{x} + 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(2x) - 6 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(6x) - 4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(4x)
$$

**Edit** after comment: You can also use Taylor expansion of $\cos x$. But then you will have series as result (without $Ci$ function).